# Jinja2 in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

how can i loop in an ansible playbook over gathered facts?
I tried:

```
...  
haproxy_backends:
  - name: 'backend'
    servers:
      {% for host in groups['app-servers'] %}
        - name: "{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_hostname'] }}"
          ip: "{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}"
      {% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work, it results in a Syntax Error. Is it even possible to use jinja in a playbook?

I use a ansible galaxy role (info.haproxy) and i don't want to change the provided templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do this.

This has to be done in a template, something like :

template/haproxy.cfg.j2 :

```
...
{% for host in groups['app-servers'] %}
backend {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_hostname'] }}
  server {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_hostname'] }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}:1234 check inter 5000 slowstart 2m

{% endfor %}
...
```

and use :

```
tasks:
  - name: Deploy haproxy config
    template: src=templatepath/haproxy.cfg.j2 dest=/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

You get the idea, YMMV.

Good luck.